# Nginx rewrite directive negative lookahead doesn't work

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

I've a simple line in my Nginx configuration:

`rewrite "^\/(?!foo-bar).*" "$scheme://destination.url" permanent;`

This should redirect everything except URLs starting with `/foo-bar`. Somehow, this line redirects everything.
For various reasons, I'm looking for a solution with a one-liner rewrite. I was able to redirect correctly using an "if" block, but that's not the goal. Also, I'm not interested in "location" blocks either.
The configuration itself doesn't include other redirections where the destination URL would be the same.

Interestingly, I could make positive lookahead work which makes the whole situation more confusing :/

Thank you!

Comment: The regular expression seems to work fine. But the behaviour you are experiencing very much depends on how you go on to process the URI `/foo-bar`. If the URI is internally rewritten to something else (e.g. /index.php), it may hit the `rewrite` rule a second time.

Comment: In the end, it'll look for the `/foo-bar/index.php` as you wrote, though it's further "down" in the server configuration. I'd think that it won't hit that rule due to the redirection.

Comment: Only some directives are ordered. The internal rewrite is likely to restart a new search from the start of the `server` block. However, `/foo-bar/index.php` should be fine as it will not match the regular expression.